# How to automatically execute a shell script when logging into Ubuntu

Tags: bash, gnome, ubuntu-11.04, .bash-profile

How do I get a script to execute automatically when I log in?  Not when the machine starts up, and not for all users, but only when I (or any specific user with the script) login via the GNOME UI.

From reading elsewhere I thought it was `.bash_profile` in my home directory, but for me it has no effect.  When I manually execute it in a terminal window by typing `~/.bash_profile` it works, but it won't run automatically when I log in.

I'm running Ubuntu 11.04.  The file permission on my .bash_profile is `-rwx------`.  No .bash_profile existed in my home directory before I created it today.

I seem to remember older versions of Linux having a `.profile` file for each user, but that doesn't work either.

How is it done?  Do I need to configure something else to get the .bash_profile to work?  Or does the per-user login script need to be in some other file?

Comment: .bash_profile, .profile and .bashrc (Which is the one actually used by ubuntu) are loaded each time you open a bash terminal. So actually I'm not sure they will be loaded if you just login into GDM.

Comment: Posting your Ubuntu version might help. In Ubuntu 10.10 .bashrc *"works for me (TM)."*

Comment: Do you mean when you log in to the GUI, or to the shell?

Comment: bash loads them when you start a new shell, so they will only get loaded when you open a terminal window or log into a virtual terminal, not when you log into Gnome (GDM).

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu 11.04, as I mentioned in the original question.

Comment: @Flimzy - I mean when I log into the GNOME GUI, not the text-based shell.

Comment: Oops. Sorry. You're not far off from my setup and I've also run into this. You can test putting an alias command alias mydir="ls -l" and logging out and back in. If mydir doesn't work, keep trying it with the "usual suspect" bash profile files that we've mentioned. Then, add your shell script to that file. Back in Solaris 2001 I only had .profile

Comment: addition to @Vlueboy: For me, .bashrc runs whenever I open a terminal window (12.04)

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/48321/how-do-i-start-applications-automatically-on-login

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could simply add the following command into System > Preferences > Startup Applications:

```
bash /full/path/to/your/script.sh
```

That should do the trick ;)

Comment: You know what, I did that before and it didn't work ... except that I didn't write "bash" before the script's path!  I'll try it with the bash later.  Out of curiosity, when you enter something via the GUI into Startup Applications, in which file is it registered?

Comment: Startup programs should be registered in `/etc/xdg/autostart`

Comment: Adding `bash /home/myusername/scriptname` to "Startup Applications" worked!  Thanks.  However this might be specific to GNOME on Ubuntu, that's why I was wondering about where the entries in that "Startup Applications" menu item are registered, as that would be more likely to be similar in other modern versions of Linux.

Comment: `/etc/xdg/autostart` appears to be a system-wide file, not specific to a user.

Comment: For later versions of ubuntu see http://askubuntu.com/questions/159887/where-did-the-startup-applications-preferences-program-go

Comment: `bash` didn't work for me. Instead `sh` did.

Answer (score 9):

So basically, as [nodiscc](https://superuser.com/users/78818/nodiscc) suggested, create a desktop launcher: **~/.config/autostart/script.desktop** with the following contents:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=Autostart Script
Exec=autostart
Icon=system-run
X-GNOME-Autostart-enabled=true
```

Then create the autostart script: **~/bin/autostart** with your bash contents:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Execute bash script below
```

Make sure that **~/bin/autostart** is executable

Answer (score 5):

You can add a line in crontab -

```
crontab -e
```

Then add this line to the file that opens up:

```
@reboot /path/to/your/cool/script
```

This will run the script at reboot. For more details see `man crontab`

Comment: I don't know why, but I can't execute .sh files on "start up applications" , therefore the easyest way to do it now, is cron

Answer (score 1):

Try `~/.xinitrc` (some info here: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xinitrc ).  Remember that anything you start in this script should be started / run in the background, or it could interfere with the X login.

Answer (score -1):

Extending [@JuanSebastianTotero answer](https://superuser.com/questions/299394/how-to-automatically-execute-a-shell-script-when-logging-into-ubuntu/744387#299396).

Instead of:

```
bash /full/path/to/your/script.sh
```

Try

```
sh /full/path/to/your/script.sh
```

`bash` didn't work for me on Ubuntu `13.04` and `14.04`. But `sh` does.

Answer (score -1):

Press

> Super (or window key)

and type

> Startup Application

Choose `Add`
In

> Command

Box, use this command below:

> bash "full/path/to/your/file.sh" --autostart

In my case, I'm using small application to swap ctrl vs alt key.
You don't need to type command every turn on your computer.

Comment: Just avoid duplicate guide, and simple to do, thanks anyway. I'll modify it.